# How to change SSH key on Google Cloud?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I need to replace the existing SSH key with a new one, but I don't see such options in Cloud admin panel.
What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just replace `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine` with the new key and use [`gcloud compute ssh`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) as you normally would to get access to your VM instances; the key will be automatically propagated to the instances that don't already have it.

If you want to remove the previous key(s), remove them from the [metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata) for all of the instances where it might have been used; the entry `attribute/sshKeys` has a list of ssh keys. See the docs for [*Default metadata*](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata#default) for more info.

See the docs for [*Setting custom metadata*](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata#custom) for how you can use `gcloud` to script changes to either project-wide or per-VM-instance metadata.

Comment: I can't make a vote up, but anyway thanks for so detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the metadata option to in VM menu options. You can delete, add or remove SSH Keys from there. For step by step process read this article.
[Add SSH Keys on Google Cloud VM](https://vipinyadav.com/blog/how-to-add-ssh-keys-in-google-cloud-vm-instance/)

Comment: The link is there. Do you have an up to date link?

Comment: @Marco link is updated.